# Mixnet: Working with thousands bit data

Tags: long-integer

I am implementing Mixnet and need to operate on thousands of bits of messages. I used C# for this and used BigInteger. This is taking much more time than I expected. Is there any way I can use Integer type for holding such long messages?

Now im using this

```
BigInteger p = BigInteger.Parse("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000543");
```

But I need something like this

```
int p = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000543;
```

If this can be done in C# or any other language then please suggest me and let me know how to do this?

Thanks